# When I click {{#linkTo}} and set the object in ember.js

Tags: view, model, controller, ember.js, action

```
 App = Ember.Application.create({
   currentProject: 21
 });
```

The  `App.currentProject` default is 21, and when I click the {{#linkTo}}, I want to set the `:project_id` in the `App.currentProject` .

Route:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('project', { path: '/project/:project_id' }, function(){
    this.resource('tasks', function(){
      this.route('new');
    });
  })
});

App.TasksRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    return App.Project.find(params.project_id);
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('content', model.tasks);
  }
})
```

Templates:

```
{{#each controller}}
  <div class="panel">
    {{#linkTo 'tasks' this}}    //click this linkTo, render to project/:project_id/tasks URL and set the App.currentProject to the :project_id at the sametime
      <div class="top"><i class="batch-big b-code"></i>
        <h6>{{title}}</h6>
      </div>
    {{/linkTo}}
  </div>
{{else}}
  <div>There are no Projects.</div>
{{/each}}
```

I don't know where `App.currentProject` set to `project_id`, in the route :

```
App.TasksRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    App.set('currentProject', params.project_id);   //I add the code to here,but it did not work
    return App.Project.find(params.project_id);
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('content', model.tasks);
  }
})
```

The template {{#linkTo}}, I did not know how to set the action.

Version information

- Require: 2.1.4
- jQuery: v1.9.1
- Ember: v1.0.0-rc.1
- Handlebars: 1.0.0-rc.3

Comment: i don't know what else might be wrong, but i think you need to change `App.currentProject.set(params.project_id);` to `App.set('currentProject', params.project_id);` or to `App.get('currentProject').set('project_id', params.project_id);` - i'm not quite sure what you're asking for.

Comment: @FinnMacCool `model: function(params){
    App.set('currentProject',params.project_id);
    console.log(params.project_id);
    return App.Project.find(params.project_id);
  }`And the console tell me the params.project_id is undefined.

Comment: ahh. well, the `params.project_id` should only be defined when you're on the `ProjectRoute`. the `TasksRoute` doesn't expect a dynamic segment. so i suggest you make the `linkTo` direct to your `ProjectRoute`, set `currentProject` there and then redirect to the `TasksRoute` instead of going there directly.

Comment: @FinnMacCool Do you have any ideas to set the `currentProject` in the `App.TasksRoute`?

Comment: hmm, maybe you could use `App.set('currentProject', this.modelFor('project').get('projectId'));` or `App.set('currentProject', this.modelFor('project').get('id'));` or something like that, but i'm not sure.